# Disable vertical scrolling in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, scroll, vertical-scrolling

In BlackBerry I have developed a screen which display a image of size
480 X 360 in background. My BB screen is of size 480 X 360. As the image is bit big in size when I scroll vertically the screen gets scrolled and disturbs my screen.

I want to lock the scrolling such that I will not be able to do vertical scrolling.

My code is as follows:

```
public LaunchXtcMsngrScreen()
{
    int intwidth = Display.getWidth();
    int intheight = Display.getHeight();


    //getting the height/width of BB screen
    Debugger.debug(UrlInfo.workflow_File,"Screen Height ="+intheight);
    Debugger.debug(UrlInfo.workflow_File,"Screen Width ="+intwidth);

    BMbackground = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("xtclogo.jpg");

    VerticalFieldManager VFM = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH 
                                                                | VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT
                                                                | VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL
                                                                | VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR)
    {
        //Override the paint method to draw the background image.
        public void paint(Graphics graphics)
        {   
            //Draw the XTC Messenger logo
            graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0,Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight(),BMbackground, 0, 0);
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
    };

    Bitmap registerbitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("register_button.PNG");
    BFregister = new ImageButtonField(registerbitmap);

    BFregister.setMargin(245,0,0,190);//vertical pos,0,0,horizontal pos

    VFM.add(BFregister);
    add(VFM);

}
```

Comment: Really?  "May be i am asking a very easy question but i really dont have time to google as of now. Please help me to do this"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add the below code as the next line of the function declaration

**super(NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL|NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);**

Answer (score 1):

If you have placed your image inside a manager then u can follow any idea viz:

1) either create a custom manager and write setExtent(480,360) in its sublayout method.
2) you can also write setExtent(480,360) in any HorizontalfieldManager or VerticalFieldManager's sublayout method

have you tried using USE_ALL_WIDTH and USE_ALL_HEIGHT in any manager?

Comment: Hi swati.yes i have used USE_ALL_WIDTH ,USE_ALL_HEIGHT  in VFM which is the parent panel and contains background image.Thanks for ur reply.i will try it out

Comment: hi swati.If i use setExtent(480.360) it gives me some ScrollView Exception on 9700 simulator.Isn't there any property of VFM directly by using which i can disble scrolling.I tried to use NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL and NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR.But it didnt work :(